# Java OOP : How to design the situation where an attribute value would decide the class of another attribute?

Tags: java, oop

Let's consider this Java class :

```
public class A {

   int att1;
   UnknownDataType att2;

}
```

And let's consider these implications :

- **IF** att1 is equal to 1 **THEN** att2 should be of type DataType1.
- **IF** att1 is equal to 2 **THEN** att2 should be of type DataType2.

I honestly cannot yet imagine how to design this, because an attribute value is influencing another intribute class.

Should simply make the class **A** as abstract class, and make **DataType1** and **DataType2** inherit from **A**? Have you guys had a similar situation?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good design. You want to use generics ...

```
public class A<UnknownDataType> {

    UnknownDataType type;

}


A<String> aString = new A<String>();
A<Integer> aInteger = new A<Integer>();
```

Comment: This is true, but given your generics you need something that would evaluate the value of att1 to initialize your object.  That should be specified.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use one of 3 approaches here:

1. Quick'n'dirty: If att2 is not exposed directly then just set its type to Object and cast when necessary using att1.
2. If the types are used in a similar way - there is room to create a common interface. In that case this becomes simple and allows to only use att1 when you need some non-trivial involvement.
3. Generics or subclassing. This fixes what att2 type is, but does not restrain you. Not easy to do if the type of att2 can change during the life cycle of the object though (unless you also implement variant 2)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tough with out knowing the exact goal of your software.  There could be a few ways to approach this.  Let's list a few potential scenarios

Is there anything in common between the UnknownDataType that you need to store?  Maybe that data type should be an interface and you store the interface instead of the data type.

Is there something in common between how you perform action on the data?  For example if UnknownDataType is used in a calculation maybe you want to replace it with a command interface and store a command to perform an action on that data. [Wiki Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

If it takes two different data types is it possible that the object is not related?  Maybe you are interested in a factory to generate your class depending on att1 and Class A is really just an interface or an abstract class.

Maybe you know the value in advance and all you want to do is use generic parameters to initialize your class

```
public class a<T>
```

If either of these don't match your scenario feel free to describe it a bit more for the best practice.